# Choose div where to load Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have my own dropdown, where I want to load [**Bootstrap Datepicker**](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and in documentation I cant find anything about that. There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/ekm0on2a/1/) about examples what I want to make

This is how looks my HTML, where I want to add datepicker

```
<div class="my-example">
  <input id="" placeholder="press to show calendar" class="input">
  <div class="dropdown">
   there is div, where I need to load my datepicker
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to load new datepicker or previous datepicker data into div with dropdown class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a div so you can load your picker:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="datetimepickerinline">
        there is div, where I need to load my datepicker
    </div>
</div>
```

and then target that new div (this way it wont conflict with the bootstrap dropdown etc):

```
$('.datetimepickerinline').datetimepicker({inline: true});
```

The key to making this work is by setting the `inline` property to `true`.

Comment: I'm glad to help!